# How to use JavaScript & .htaccess for SEO?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, web-applications, seo

How can I use **only** *JavaScript* and/or *.htaccess* to map a request for:

`http://example.com/map/new_york`

to:

```
http://example.com/map?city=new_york
```

Without the user seeing the URL redirect?

**UPDATE**:

Since there seems to be a lot of confusion here, I'll provide more detail. I want to accomplish Search Engine Optimization (SEO) for my map application. The map resides on my web server at `http://example.com/map`. I want to allow people to deep link to a city of their choosing, which is in the form of `http://example.com/map/?city=new_york`. Since I want SEO, the URL should instead look like: `http://example.com/map/new_york`.

Without using any type of server-side programming (PHP/Python/etc), how can I accomplish this use case with only JavaScript and/or .htaccess?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: I've updated my original post to give more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use JavaScript to do this.

However, you CAN do this via .htaccess, if you have mod_rewrite installed on the web server that is hosting your website.

See this link for creating "Rewrite" entries in your .htaccess file:

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

(there are plenty of resources on the internet to do this, search for ".htaccess rewrite"

**UPDATED**:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^map/([^/]+) /map?city=$1 [NC]
```

That should rewrite all requests to `map/[ANYTHING]` to `/map?city=[ANYTHING]`

Comment: everything I've found on the Internet states Apache will force a redirect. I don't want to user to be redirected to the /?city=... page. How do I overcome this?

Comment: A rewrite is NOT a redirect. Adding "rewrite" rules to your .htaccess will make apache accept a request to /map/city and actually map it on the back end to your actual file/querystring combo - this is NOT a redirect, the user will be served a response to their original request.

Comment: This will *always* be the case. How else is the browser supposed to know that ``http://example.com/page1`` points at ``http://example.com/page2``? You *can* use Javascript and ``window.location``, but this will still be 2 requests. Also, many search bots don't do Javascript, so it's bad SEO practice to rely on Javascript.

Comment: @rkaregaran, Do you mind being more specific with the actual rewrite rule I'd use. I can't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: @Jacjoi, please see my revised answer. Let me know if that works or the errors that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://example.com/map/new_york';
var u = url.split("/");
document.write(u[0]+'/'+u[1]+'/'+u[2]+'/'+u[3]+'?city='+u[4]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NzXmd/

Comment: This won't work. I've updated my original post to give more details.